# How to find non-normalized eigen vector?

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is to validate whether an eigen vector is part of an nxn square.

The formula that I know `A * x = lamda * x`

Example

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,-1],
              [6,4]])
eigvalues, eigvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)
```

The `eigvectors` output are normalized eigen vector.

[According to this website](https://byjus.com/jee/normalized-and-decomposition-of-eigenvectors/#:%7E:text=Normalized%20eigenvector%20is%20nothing%20but,the%20vector%20of%20length%20one.), normalized eigen vector is an eigvector having unit length.

In this case I want to check whether `eigen vector` is part of an `n x n` square matrix.

```
x = [ 1
      3 ]
```

So, what I did is that to multiply the eigen vector in question with the square root of the eigen vector:

```
normalized_eigvector = np.array([1,3]) * npsqrt(1 + 9)

np.array_equal(normalized_eigvector, np.absolute(eigectors[1]))
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: You should not take the absolute value of the vector: you can have `a == np.abs(b)` but `a != b`.  Also the `sqrt(1 + 9)` is the norm of the vetor, so to get a unit vector you should divide it by its norm. Finally, for each unit eigenvector u , -u is also a unit eigenvector so you should take this in account

Comment: @PlainRavioli It turns out that I have wrong formula `A.x = λx`. Proving that `x= [1,3]` is vector of `A = [[1,6],[-1,4]]` is as easy as doing `A @ x == λ * x`